# Finalizers not finalized for ThreadPoolExecutor, causing a memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I run client code inside my application, much like a WebServer deploys/undeploys WebApps.

So I created a custom `ClassLoader` that gets discarded to get rid of the client code. However, this doesn't work properly. When executing and analyzing with [Elipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), I can see that the objects and the classloader are never garbage collected: [image: Path to Memory Leak]

Somehow the problem seems to be related to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which implements a `finalize()` method. It was mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499886/java-ill-defined-finalize-method-to-create-memory-leak), that finalizer methods are evil and can cause `OutOfMemoryErrors`, because Finalizer thread runs with lower priority. However, when analyzing the application and thread stack with [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), the Finalizer thread is not busy but waiting for new work to arrive:

```
"Finalizer" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fdb1484f800 nid=0x2603 in Object.wait() [0x000000010aaf6000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 - waiting on <0x000000079aaadf10> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
 at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
 - locked <0x000000079aaadf10> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
 at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
 at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None
```

JavaDoc of `ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)`:

```
Removes the next reference object in this queue, blocking until either 
one becomes available or the given timeout period expires.
```

Any ideas what can cause this problem and what to do about it? Every input is highly appreciated!

**Edit:** We are using jdk1.7.0_09.jdk, so I guess it has nothing to do with [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243487/objects-not-being-finalized-and-finalizer-thread-not-doing-anything?rq=1).

**Edit:** When I let the application run long enough (and execute and discard enough client code) I do get OutOfMemoryErrors, so the VM should garbage collect the classes. Also, using the `-verbose:gc` flag, I see the following log output after the classes should be ready for finalization and just before taking the HeapDump:

```
[Full GC 57007K->52790K(149544K), 0.2997010 secs]
```

Which means, that a full GC just took place.

Comment: Are you actually getting OOME's? Because without those there is no pressure on the JVM to collect. And of course, dumping the whole application without proper shutdown is a sure road to failure.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Thanks for pointing that out, adjusted the question accordingly... but what do you mean with 'dumping the whole application without proper shutdown'?

Comment: Just losing the ClassLoader is not enough to properly dispose of an application. A reasonable architecture will provide a callback to the application where it would run the cleanup procedure, shutting down the executor service, for example.

Comment: The `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()` method gets called. I just provided a ThreadPoolExecutor without `finalize()` (via -Xbootclasspath/p:) and now there are some other objects which are referenced from a Finalizer. Since no additional thread is still running ... how can that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying everything else, I updated the JDK and ... now the problem is gone. Now we are using `jdk1.7.0_51` instead of `jdk1.7.0_09`.

Hope this helps someone...